# DJI Windows SDK - Example code is not retrieving files on the SDK

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I am using the latest version of Windows SDK and connecting with Mavic 2 Pro, which has been updated to latest firmware. I have plugged on the Mavic a Lexar MicroSD of 16GB and 633x.

I am able to run the example code an connect to the Drone and get name, velocity updates and video. However when I try to get the files on the drone, using the playback. when I am on the play back window, I set the *workmode* button is on *green*, which checking on the variables is set on **TRANSCODE** mode. Then I click on *Reload* button and I get the messages REQUEST_TIMEOUT: [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrBKN.png)

I have tried also with a SanDisk MicroSD of 32GB Ultra with same results. I have debug the code and seen that the function is called.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem. Im running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities

Here is a checklist, cross them out 1 by 1 to rule out the issue.
Here is a checklist, cross them out 1 by 1 to rule out the issue.

1. USB Authority Configuration in UWP
2. Connection sequence
   Make sure that before connecting using your cable, your P4P V2.0 remote controller is off.

   Connect the remote controller to your computer using Micro-USB cable.

   Turn on your remote controller.

   Make sure you have not open the DJI software like DJI Assistant 2.

DJI Windows SDK Applications are not able to communicate with the aircrafts at the same time.

3 Make sure that you have installed DJI Assistant 2 and have enabled all the driver intallation while installing DJI Assistant 2.

4 WinUSB Driver

**5 Make sure all dll are in the correct place e.g. DJIwindowsSDK.dll pthread_dll.dll and libcrypto-1.1.dll**

6 Make sure the account that used for App Key registration is same as DJI app account

If you still cant solve it by then, send your question and your attempts to dev@dji.com for help. If you know someone in DJI or you have a premium support account, you can get faster respond(within 24 hours)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I double check everything: number 3 is working because I get information about the drone (e.g. name and velocity). I get FVP, which means number 4 is check. I am just running the example but I double check the files and they are ok. The only think that I don't know how they are related is the number 6 because I am not logging to my account from the example, I just go directly to the playback panel.

Comment: there are many small little trick that no one says and you have to find it out.  There are other cases such as when using OSDK with DJI simulator, you have to connect and run sdk.lauch b4 running simulator, or it wont connect.      have you double checked on winusb installation? its also one of the easy to fail part.   If really can not, just contact DJI support